# Rest API - spring controllers and resources

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am writing a rest API which is quite simple, this is my first attempt and I will be using spring framework.

The test app only deals with products, categories and types . A product has a type, a category has many types and a product can also have multiple  categories which it can fit into so I am wondering if I should create a spring controller for each.

If I did that then would it be possible to get a product back when calling through the category controller and would this be o.k?

I mean something like this:

```
/categories/{category_id}/types/{type_id}/products
```

To me this would filter by category, then a type and get all products for the type, or is this not restful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rest patterns should be simple and not layered.

If you wish to retrieve things, they should be straightforward like:

```
/categories/{category_id}
/products/{product_id}
/types/{type_id}
```

For filtering, you should make use of query string instead of url path because url path cares about order/hierarchy, whereas filtering should not be concerned with order.

Comment: ok this is exactly what I was looking for, so if I wanted to filter for a product then I do something like: /products?typeId=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This API looks fine to me. And if you are looking for the implementation see below.

The function below works just fine

```
@RequestMapping(value="/categories/{category_id}/types/{type_id}/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void test(
        @PathVariable String  category_id,
        @PathVariable String type_id)
{

}
```

If you need you can bind property editors for your category and type objects and pass them as objects to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a ProductController that can get products by 1 or more parameters. I would use query parameters instead of path params, since path params will get confusing esp. when you query for multiple categories or types. So have a service like;

```
/product/list?category=a,b,c&type=abcd
/product/get/id=123 or /product/get/{id}
```

You can have controllers for categories & types which allow listing and create/update/delete (if supported) for them.

```
/category/get?id=123
/types/get?id=123
```

Comment: Ok so its ok to use a query string for rest then? I need to read a little more I think!

Comment: And yes a lot less confusing.. I didnt think about that.

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly you would model this as

```
/category/
/product/
/type/
```

(for POST, with trailing ID for PUT and DELETE) and then you can query (GET) the products and categories as follows

```
/product/?category_id=123
/product/?type_id=12
/category/?name=big+items
```

When you have a 1:1 relationship you could also consider combining category and type into a single entity. Perhaps the type is an attribute of the category instead, or vice versa.

Based on your specification,

```
/categories/{category_id}/types/{type_id}/products
```

{type_id} is really redundant because of the 1:1 relationship between category and type.

On the other hand,

```
/categories/{category_id}/products/
```

is fine, but lets you only search for one category at a time.

ps. "type" is often a reserved keyword and can lead to strange error messages